# how to add same nodes two times with append()?

Tags: javascript

I want to add node named as card into container two times but the way1 didn't worked.
So i solved way2. But it looks like not good code. so i want to anohter way
Please teach me.

```
html

<div class="container">
      <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-4">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/600" class="w-100">
            <h5 class="title">Card title</h5>
            <p class="price">price : 70000</p>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

```
js   //way1  didn't added two times

      let card = document.querySelector('.row').cloneNode(true) //want to add in container two times
      let container = document.querySelector('.container');
      
      container.append(card)
      container.append(card)
```

```
js   //way2 to solve but doesn't look good
 
      let card = document.querySelector('.row').cloneNode(true);
      let card2 = document.querySelector('.row').cloneNode(true);
      let container = document.querySelector('.container');
      
      container.append(card, card2)
```

Comment: To clarify, "way1" does append twice, but you are appending the same element and one element can't exist in two locations at once, so it is instantly "moved" by the second append.

Comment: The second way is the only way to make it work, if you wan't two clones you have to clone it twice. 'doesn't look good' doesn't really come into it. You could certainly clean it up a little: only query the DOM once, use a loop of the appropriate length to clone without repeating code, or move the whole process to a helper function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to 're-clone' the row to be able to append it again. You can't append the same elements again. Try using a clone function, something like

```js
const container = document.querySelector(`.container`);
const cloneRow = _ => 
 document.querySelector(`.container .row:first-child`).cloneNode(true);
container.append(cloneRow());
container.append(cloneRow());
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50" class="w-100">
      <h5 class="title">Card title</h5>
      <p class="price">price : 70000</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Alternative is to use the html of the row to copy/append:

```js
const container = document.querySelector(`.container`);
const nwRow = document.querySelector(`.row`).innerHTML;
// add 5 rows
for (let i = 0; i < 5; i += 1) {
  container.append( 
  Object.assign(
   document.createElement(`div`),
   {className: `row`, innerHTML: nwRow} ) );
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50" class="w-100">
      <h5 class="title">Card title</h5>
      <p class="price">price : 70000</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```